# How can I add a custom attribute to React's HTMLAttributes from a library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say I'm building a re-usable library for use in a React application. This library looks for certain DOM elements with certain attributes and values.

For example, it looks for DIV with an attribute of 'foo' that can equal 'bar' or 'baz'.

Both the library and its consumers are written in Typescript.

Now when I try to instantiate a DIV element in my consumer code:

```
// consumer/Consumer.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import 'library';

export const Consumer = () =>
  <div foo="bar">Hello</div>;
```

I get a type error

`Type '{ children: string; type: string; onClick: () => void; foo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.
        Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.ts(2322)
      (property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.button: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>`

I can fix this by adding [merged a module declaration and interface declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to my consumer's code:

```
// consumer/Consumer.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import 'library';

declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
    readonly foo?: 'bar' | 'baz';
  }
}

export const Consumer = () =>
  <div foo="bar">Hello</div>;
```

However, I think this should really be done in my *library's* code, rather than the consumer's code. After all, it's the library's job to define its contracts, not its consumer's job. The consumer should be able to import whichever interfaces the library defines from the library.

So I tried moving the declaration to my library code. I wasn't sure where to put it, so I decided to just append it to the index.ts file, which exports all the library's components:

```
// library/src/index.ts

export * from './LibraryComponent1.tsx';
export * from './LibraryComponent2.tsx';

// added declaration here:
declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
    readonly foo?: 'bar' | 'baz';
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. When I recompile the library and re-link it to my consumer, I get the same type errors as above.

I've tried:

- Using `declare namespace` instead of `declare module`
- Adding `export` in front of `interface HTMLAttributes` in the library
- Putting the declaration in a different file

  - types/index.d.ts
  - src/types.d.ts
  - src/index.d.ts
  - src/test.ts
- Importing the library in various ways

  - import 'library';
  - import 'library/src';
  - import 'library/src/types';
  - import 'library/types';
  - import { HTMLAttributes } from 'library';
  - etc.

What am I missing here? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I am not a TypeScript user myself (though I've dealt with it a little bit in working with third-party packages), so I apologize if this answer betrays some of my ignorance in this area.

It seems that you are trying to put an inappropriate responsibility on your library. It makes sense to me that your library should be able to say that `foo` is a valid property for a div within one of the library's components, but you seem to be suggesting that the library should be able to have a side-effect of changing the validation of elements that are NOT produced by components of the library.

To make sure the distinction is clear. It seems natural for me for the library to have something like (assuming that the appropriate TypeScript would be applied to make this valid):

```
// library code
export const LibComponent1 = (props) => {
   return <div foo="bar">{props.children}</div>
}
```

and then allow a consumer to use `LibComponent1` without issue. But it seems like bad library behavior to allow changing the TypeScript validation for all divs in components defined outside of the library to allow a property of "foo". If multiple libraries did things like this, they could easily conflict with one another or hide issues in other code.

Comment: Good advice. Don’t know why I didn’t think of that, but it’s a valid design point.

Comment: On second thoughts... is this really an inappropriate responsibility? When a Typescript library exports, say, a function, as part of that it constrains the parameters that can be passed to a function. E.g. function `foo` only takes parameters `a: string` and `b: number`. Is it so different with a React component constraining its `children` prop to only take children that implement certain properties? Given that a React component is ultimately just a function (or an ES6 class)?

Comment: It would be fine for it to constrain its children (e.g. to require certain properties or disallow certain properties), but those constraints shouldn’t be allowed to be incompatible with the definition of the child type that it is expecting. Its constraints should just be limiting the child type to something more specific. In your function example taking in a string and a number, it’s the difference between requiring the number to be within a certain range (more specific) vs. requiring that the number end with the characters “zc” (incompatible with the definition of number).

Comment: I'm having further thoughts on this. The problem I'm having doesn't seem to be about limiting props of elements passed to children, per-se. Rather, it's about making those limitations work with elements that aren't part of my library, e.g. React's built-in `<div>`, `<span>`, etc. I want the consumer to be able to provide whatever elements they want, but I also want them to be able, and required, to provide the properties specific to my library. I'll have a further think about this; perhaps there are analogs in other languages/frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

Say you want to accept extra attributes in your custom component, and use the spread operator (like `...rest`) for the preexisting attributes. Here´s how you do it:

```
interface Props{
  icon?: string; 
}

type Button = Props & React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;

function Button({ 
  icon,
  ...rest
}: Button) {
  return (
    <button 
      {...rest}
    >
     {icon && <span>{icon}</span>}
     {children}       
    </button>
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't solving the actual problem I'm having. I'm not trying set only the values that are already defined by React's `<div>`. Rather, I am trying to declare new properties for React's `<div>` that weren't there already. That way, I can set those properties on a `<div>` and then pick them up from the parent element, which I define myself in my own framework. However, it looks like this isn't possible; at least, not without defining those new properties in the consumer code, rather than in my library's code where they should be.